# Transiting in Frankfurt - Canadian visa expires on transit, but have a US B1/B2 - enough?

Tags: visas, transit, germany, canada, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen and have a valid Canadian visa until April 16 and I am boarding Lufthansa the same day; so while I'm in transit on April 17th, my Canadian visa is not legal. I do have a valid US B1/B2 visa.

Is that enough for transiting through Frankfurt?

Comment: If you're not in Canada when your visa expires, how would that be a problem?

Comment: @GregHewgill Some countries allow transit without a visa if you have valid visas for other countries, especially US and Canada.

Comment: @user2629746 I edited in what I'm guessing your citizenship based off your question's tags.  Can you please update it if that's incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - you're good!

Longer answer...

Germany normally requires a visa for Indian nationals, even if only in transit - however there are a number of exceptions that allow air-side transit without visa (TWOV).

One of those exceptions is if you have a Canadian visa, and you are in transit either on the way to Canada, or on the way to your home country (regardless of where you are traveling from).  Clearly your concern here is that your Canadian visa will be expired by the time you arrive in Frankfurt, however this is NOT a problem!  As long as your visa was valid when you commenced your return trip, then you will be allowed transit.

So your expired Canadian visa IS sufficient for you to transit Frankfurt.

Another of the exceptions is the same as above, but for a US visa.  As you have a valid US visa, you are also covered there.

So your unexpired US visa IS also sufficient for you to transit Frankfurt.

Note that in both cases you will need to remain airside, and will need to be scheduled to depart FRA within 24 hours of arrival.

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a specific reason why these countries are exempted ? The reason why I am asking is I am travelling with my family (wife and kid), and they have a valid canadian visa on transit and my kid dont have a US visa.

Comment: There are a number of 3rd country visas that are valid for transit in Germany.  The implication is that Germany trusts the decision of those countries to give you a visa enough to consider it an indication that it is safe to allow you to transit airside at a German airport.

Comment: Being in transit to Canada or returning to your home country is *not* required if the visa is still valid (it is indeed required when returning after having used a visa).

Answer (score 4):

According to [Transit Visa Regulation for Indian Residents](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855):

> 3. Indian nationals can Transit without Visa via FRA or MUC if holding a valid visa for the destination and a valid Visa for any of the following countries
>
> Bulgaria, Canada, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Liechtenstein, Romania, UK and USA (the approval notice I-797 is not valid document for visa free airport transit).

If your Canadian visa expires in transit, and you still have a valid USA visa, then you should still be eligible for visa-free transit in Frankfurt (since your destination is India).